# Can Parallel.For be optimized for very short-running operations?

Tags: c#, .net, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library

I am aware of tasks that offer fine grained control for short running tasks but I have a situation where it is more natural to use a foreach loop. The question is, is it possible to tell Parallel.For to expect short-running operations and use as many threads as possible to max out the CPU?

If not, then what method would you suggest to parallelize:

```
bool [,] grid = new bool [1000, 1000];
for (int y=0; y<1000; y++)
    for (int x=0; x<1000; x++)
        // Ignore the bounds error. This is just to illustrate a very short operation.
        grid[x, y] |= grid[x-1, y+1];
```

Comment: Your CPU only has so much capacity.  Doing things in parallel does not magically pull in extra processing power from some unknown source.  If running it in serial maxes out the processor, running it parallel is not going to gain anything, and in fact will probably *slow down* the operation due to the overhead of the threads and context switching.  The only way you can really gain is if your short operation is some sort of **high IO-wait** operation that isn't CPU-bound.  So you can you tell us a little more about your real operation?

Comment: You can for example divide your matrix into 4 pieces and run 4 threads. (Boundries should be handled separately of course)

Comment: If there are a bunch of short-running threads the `Parallel.For` will effectively already be optimized.  You can use `ParallelOptions` to override that: `Parallel.For(1, 10, new ParallelOptions {MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount*2}, i => { /* TODO something with i */ });` but that likely will have an negative impact on performance, not a positive impact.

Comment: @PeterRitchie: Yes, going above the `ProcessorCount` would almost certainly have a negative impact for non-I/O operations. Your example of `ProcessorCount*2` could prove beneficial in some cases with hyper threading enabled and small, non-parallelizable operations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The question is, is it possible to tell Parallel.For to expect short-running operations and use as many threads as possible to max out the CPU?

Yes, you can do this by making a `Partitioner<T>` and handling the partitioning yourself.  For details, see [How to: Speed Up Small Loop Bodies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd560853.aspx).

However, in your case, it might be better to just parallelize the outer loop, and leave the inner loop sequential inside of each of the outer `Parallel.For` loop bodies.  This would give each work item enough instructions that it would probably use the processor adequately.

That being said, this is a situation where .NET will likely not do a great job with `Parallel.For` - at least not without some extra work.  By assiging values to the *same array* in parallel, you're going to be introducing [false sharing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_sharing) due to the implicit array bounds check, which reads from the same location (just before the start of the array).

There are various approaches to working around this - one option might be to switch from a multidimensional to a jagged array, for example.  With the proper indexing and looping, this can reduce the number of writes to "shared" arrays.  Another option would be to use unsafe code and pointers instead of direct array access, as this avoids the bounds checks, but requires very careful coding.

Comment: As with any perf optimization, make sure to *measure* before changing code from the simpler implementation.  For instance, I've seen people complicate code to avoid this in cases where there wasn't a runtime bounds check (since static analysis showed it wasn't needed :)  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/clrcodegeneration/archive/2009/08/13/array-bounds-check-elimination-in-the-clr.aspx

Comment: @JamesManning: Yes, I agree. In this case though I will be creating and measuring multiple implementations as this portion of the application is time critical.

Comment: @Reed: I will try all approaches in any case. I'm new to partitioning and although I have read your example, could you elaborate the concept in lay man's terms? I'm trying to understand 'how' it is beneficial (not necessarily for my case). An example scenario where custom partitioning could benefit as opposed to default partitioning.

Comment: @RaheelKhan Basically, by handling the partitioning yourself, you can make the "small body" a much larger body.  It allows you to "group" many of the elements together into one element, so you're reducing the relative overhead of the threading.